# error while consuming a RestFul WebService

Tags: web-services

I have created a web service -

```
@Path("/info")
public class RestFulService {
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String getPlain()
{
    return " Web Service created";
}
}
```

When I am accessing through localhost browser is rendering - "Web Service created".

But when I am trying to consume this web service through a different app I am getting 404 error code - "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 404
    at RestConsumer.main(RestConsumer.java:28)
"

Code inside RestConsumer.java -

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String uri = "http://localhost:8080/RestFul/rest/info";
        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
        conn.connect();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));
        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }
        conn.disconnect();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest the required change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a basic setting problem in Eclipse EE Refer to this Youtube link at 6:54

It gives a step by step guide to rectify the same. Hope this helps[tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b42CJ0r-1to&feature=relmfu)

Comment: I think you forgot to add the link